# не работает AJAX + PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

имеется файл `forma.php` где находится `HTML форма`, скрипт на `PHP` который должен принимать данные с `AJAX` методом `POST` и также валидации для форми на `JavaScript` данные c формы должен отправлять `AJAX` на обработку в `PHP` но переменные пустые, данные с `AJAX` не доходят или с форми в `AJAX` , 
подскажите пожалуйста, где здесь ошибка, заранее благодарю!

P.S. самая валидация работает, данные до нажатия 'Отправить' были внесение коректно.

**forma.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit-form'])){
    $errors = array();
       if(empty($_POST['title'])){$errors[] = "Пожалуйста, введите названия";}
       else{$title = clean($_POST['title']);}
       if(empty($_POST['des'])){$errors[]= "Пожалуйста, введите описания";}
       else{$ingredients = clean($_POST['des']);}   
       if(empty($_POST['des2'])){$errors[] = "Пожалуйста, введите описания 2";}
       else{$directians = clean($_POST['des']);}
       if(empty($_POST['img'])){$errors[] = "Пожалуйста, вставте ссылку на изображения";}
       else{$img = clean($_POST['img']);}
    ....
```

**HTML форма внутри файла "forma.php"**

```
...

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validation.js"></script>
...

<main class="content">
    <form id="feedback-form" action="#" method="Post">
        *Назва:<br>
    <input id="title" type="text" name="title" class="input_title">
    <div class="error-box">&nbsp;</div><br><br>
        *URL Image: <br>
    <input id="input_img", type="text" name="img" class="input_img">
    <div class="error-box">&nbsp;</div><br><br>
        *Описания: <br>
    <textarea id="des" rows="10" cols="45" name="des"</textarea>
    <div class="error-box">&nbsp;</div><br><br>
        *Описания 2: <br>
    <textarea id="des2" rows="10" cols="45" name="des2"></textarea>
    <div class="error-box">&nbsp;</div><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit-form" value="Отправить"  class="button15" id="button15">
<br>
</form>
</main>
```

**validation.js** // AJAX

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

     // Устанавливаем обработчик потери фокуса для всех полей ввода текста
     $('input#title, input#input_img, textarea#des, textarea#des2').unbind().blur( function(){

        // Для удобства записываем обращения к атрибуту и значению каждого поля в переменные 
         var id = $(this).attr('id');
         var val = $(this).val();

       // После того, как поле потеряло фокус, перебираем значения id, совпадающее с id данного поля
       switch(id)
       {

             // Проверка поля "Имя"
             case 'title':
                var rv_title = /^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+$/; // используем регулярное выражение

                // Eсли длина имени больше 2ух символов, оно не пустое и удовлетворяет рег. выражению,
                // то добавляем этому полю класс .not_error,
                // и ниже в контейнер для ошибок выводим слово "Принято", т.е. валидация для этого поля пройдена успешно

                if(val.length > 2 && val != '' && rv_title.test(val))
                {
                   $(this).addClass('ttt').css('background', 'rgb(250, 255, 189)');
                   $(this).addClass('not_error');
                   $(this).next('.error-box').text('Принято')
                                             .css('color','green')
                }

              // Иначе, мы удаляем класс not-error, и заменяем его на класс error, говоря о том что поле содержит ошибку валидации,
              // и ниже в наш контейнер выводим сообщение об ошибке и параметры для верной валидации

                else
                {
                   $(this).addClass('ttt').css('background', '#FFCFCF');
                   $(this).removeClass('not_error').addClass('error');
                   $(this).next('.error-box').html('&bull; поле "Назва" обовязкове для заповнення<br> &bull; довжина назви повина становити не менше двох символів')
                                              .css('color','red')

                }
            break;

                          // Проверка поля "Сообщение"
          case 'input_img':
              var rv_url_img = /https?\:\/\//;

              if(val.length > 2 && val != '' && rv_url_img.test(val))
              {
                 $(this).addClass('ttt').css('background', 'rgb(250, 255, 189)');
                 $(this).addClass('not_error');
                 $(this).next('.error-box').text('Принято')
                                           .css('color','green')
              }
              else
              {
                 $(this).addClass('ttt').css('background', '#FFCFCF');
                 $(this).removeClass('not_error').addClass('error');
                 $(this).next('.error-box').html('&bull; поле повино начитатися з "http://" <br> &bull; поле "URL Image" обовязкове для заповнення')
                                           .css('color','red')
              }
          break;

                        // Проверка поля "Сообщение"
          case 'des':
              if(val != '' && val.length < 5000)
              {   
                 $(this).addClass('ttt').css('background', 'rgb(250, 255, 189)');
                 $(this).addClass('not_error');
                 $(this).next('.error-box').text('Принято')
                                           .css('color','green')

              }
              else
              {  
                 $(this).addClass('ttt').css('background', '#FFCFCF');
                 $(this).removeClass('not_error').addClass('error');
                 $(this).next('.error-box').html('&bull; поле "Інгредієнти" обовязкове для заповнення')
                                           .css('color','red')
              }
          break;

                                      // Проверка поля "Сообщение"
          case 'des2':
              if(val != '' && val.length < 5000)
              {   
                 $(this).addClass('ttt').css('background', 'rgb(250, 255, 189)');
                 $(this).addClass('not_error');
                 $(this).next('.error-box').text('Принято')
                                           .css('color','green')

              }
              else
              {  
                 $(this).addClass('ttt').css('background', '#FFCFCF');
                 $(this).removeClass('not_error').addClass('error');
                 $(this).next('.error-box').html('&bull; поле "Опис" обовязкове для заповнення')
                                           .css('color','red')
              }
          break;


       } // end switch(...)

     }); // end blur()


     // Теперь отправим наше письмо с помощью AJAX
     $('form#feedback-form').submit(function(e){

         // Запрещаем стандартное поведение для кнопки submit
         e.preventDefault();

         // После того, как мы нажали кнопку "Отправить", делаем проверку,
         // если кол-во полей с классов .not_error равно 4(так как у нас всего 3 поля), то есть все поля заполнены верно,
         // выполняем наш Ajax сценарий и отправляем письмо адресату

         if($('.not_error').length == 4)
         {  

            // Eще одним моментов является то, что в качестве указания данных для передачи обработчику send.php, мы обращаемся $(this) к нашей форме,
            // и вызываем метод .serialize().
            // Это очень удобно, т.к. он сразу возвращает сгенерированную строку с именами и значениями выбранных элементов формы.

             $.ajax({
                    url: '#',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),

                    beforeSend: function(xhr, textStatus){ 
                         $('form#feedback-form :input').attr('disabled','disabled');
                    },

                   success: function(response){
                        $('form#feedback-form :input').removeAttr('disabled');
                        $('form#feedback-form :text, textarea').val('').removeClass().next('.error-box').text('');
                        alert(response);
                   }
            }); // end ajax({...})
        }
        else
        {
          return false;
        }
        // Иначе, если количество полей с данным классом не равно значению 3 мы возвращаем false,
        // останавливая отправку сообщения в невалидной форме


   }); // end submit()


  }); // end script
```

Comment: Но вы ведь сами можете посмотреть консоль в браузере при отправке -  реально ли отправляется что-то или нет, а также сделать на стороне сервера `print_r($_POST);`...ведь это так просто...... .....или и там и там у вас отображает данные?

Comment: `@АлексейШиманский` , `print_r($_POST);` ничего не вывел

Comment: Соответственно у вас ничего и не отсылается. Соответственно можно включить дебаг в браузере и посмотреть почему

Comment: не могу понять в чем дело :(

Answer (score 5):

вы же указали `url: '#'` а нужно было `url: 'forma.php'`, и теперь он передает

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

     // Устанавливаем обработчик потери фокуса для всех полей ввода текста
     $('input#title, input#input_img, textarea#des, textarea#des2').unbind().blur( function(){

        // Для удобства записываем обращения к атрибуту и значению каждого поля в переменные 
         var id = $(this).attr('id');
         var val = $(this).val();

       // После того, как поле потеряло фокус, перебираем значения id, совпадающее с id данного поля
       switch(id)
       {

             // Проверка поля "Имя"
             case 'title':
                var rv_title = /^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+$/; // используем регулярное выражение

                // Eсли длина имени больше 2ух символов, оно не пустое и удовлетворяет рег. выражению,
                // то добавляем этому полю класс .not_error,
                // и ниже в контейнер для ошибок выводим слово "Принято", т.е. валидация для этого поля пройдена успешно

                if(val.length > 2 && val != '' && rv_title.test(val))
                {
                   $(this).addClass('ttt').css('background', 'rgb(250, 255, 189)');
                   $(this).addClass('not_error');
                   $(this).next('.error-box').text('Принято')
                                             .css('color','green')
                }

              // Иначе, мы удаляем класс not-error, и заменяем его на класс error, говоря о том что поле содержит ошибку валидации,
              // и ниже в наш контейнер выводим сообщение об ошибке и параметры для верной валидации

                else
                {
                   $(this).addClass('ttt').css('background', '#FFCFCF');
                   $(this).removeClass('not_error').addClass('error');
                   $(this).next('.error-box').html('&bull; поле "Назва" обовязкове для заповнення<br> &bull; довжина назви повина становити не менше двох символів')
                                              .css('color','red')

                }
            break;

                          // Проверка поля "Сообщение"
          case 'input_img':
              var rv_url_img = /https?\:\/\//;

              if(val.length > 2 && val != '' && rv_url_img.test(val))
              {
                 $(this).addClass('ttt').css('background', 'rgb(250, 255, 189)');
                 $(this).addClass('not_error');
                 $(this).next('.error-box').text('Принято')
                                           .css('color','green')
              }
              else
              {
                 $(this).addClass('ttt').css('background', '#FFCFCF');
                 $(this).removeClass('not_error').addClass('error');
                 $(this).next('.error-box').html('&bull; поле повино начитатися з "http://" <br> &bull; поле "URL Image" обовязкове для заповнення')
                                           .css('color','red')
              }
          break;

                        // Проверка поля "Сообщение"
          case 'des':
              if(val != '' && val.length < 5000)
              {   
                 $(this).addClass('ttt').css('background', 'rgb(250, 255, 189)');
                 $(this).addClass('not_error');
                 $(this).next('.error-box').text('Принято')
                                           .css('color','green')

              }
              else
              {  
                 $(this).addClass('ttt').css('background', '#FFCFCF');
                 $(this).removeClass('not_error').addClass('error');
                 $(this).next('.error-box').html('&bull; поле "Інгредієнти" обовязкове для заповнення')
                                           .css('color','red')
              }
          break;

                                      // Проверка поля "Сообщение"
          case 'des2':
              if(val != '' && val.length < 5000)
              {   
                 $(this).addClass('ttt').css('background', 'rgb(250, 255, 189)');
                 $(this).addClass('not_error');
                 $(this).next('.error-box').text('Принято')
                                           .css('color','green')

              }
              else
              {  
                 $(this).addClass('ttt').css('background', '#FFCFCF');
                 $(this).removeClass('not_error').addClass('error');
                 $(this).next('.error-box').html('&bull; поле "Опис" обовязкове для заповнення')
                                           .css('color','red')
              }
          break;


       } // end switch(...)

     }); // end blur()


     // Теперь отправим наше письмо с помощью AJAX
     $('form#feedback-form').submit(function(e){

         // Запрещаем стандартное поведение для кнопки submit
         e.preventDefault();

         // После того, как мы нажали кнопку "Отправить", делаем проверку,
         // если кол-во полей с классов .not_error равно 4(так как у нас всего 3 поля), то есть все поля заполнены верно,
         // выполняем наш Ajax сценарий и отправляем письмо адресату

         if($('.not_error').length == 4)
         {  

            // Eще одним моментов является то, что в качестве указания данных для передачи обработчику send.php, мы обращаемся $(this) к нашей форме,
            // и вызываем метод .serialize().
            // Это очень удобно, т.к. он сразу возвращает сгенерированную строку с именами и значениями выбранных элементов формы.

             $.ajax({
                    url: 'forma.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),

                    beforeSend: function(xhr, textStatus){ 
                         $('form#feedback-form :input').attr('disabled','disabled');
                    },

                   success: function(response){
                        $('form#feedback-form :input').removeAttr('disabled');
                        $('form#feedback-form :text, textarea').val('').removeClass().next('.error-box').text('');
                        alert(response);
                   }
            }); // end ajax({...})
        }
        else
        {
          return false;
        }
        // Иначе, если количество полей с данным классом не равно значению 3 мы возвращаем false,
        // останавливая отправку сообщения в невалидной форме


   }); // end submit()


  }); // end script
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="content">
    <form id="feedback-form" action="#" method="Post">
        *Назва:<br>
    <input id="title" type="text" name="title" class="input_title">
    <div class="error-box">&nbsp;</div><br><br>
        *URL Image: <br>
    <input id="input_img", type="text" name="img" class="input_img">
    <div class="error-box">&nbsp;</div><br><br>
        *Описания: <br>
    <textarea id="des" rows="10" cols="45" name="des"></textarea>
    <div class="error-box">&nbsp;</div><br><br>
        *Описания 2: <br>
    <textarea id="des2" rows="10" cols="45" name="des2"></textarea>
    <div class="error-box">&nbsp;</div><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit-form" value="Отправить"  class="button15" id="button15">
<br>
</form>
</main>
```

Comment: а почему нельзя '#' использовать ? `php` и `ajax` они же находятся  в одном файле

Comment: хотите сказать что ваша форма и php код для обработки данных находятся в файле forma.php? В таком случае у вас response будет возвращать ту же HTML страницу с формой. Ведь так не делается.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите в хром f12 вкладка console что происходит при нажатия.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/84156)

Comment: Извините не туда писал.